# Visual Studio Hotkeys C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, hotkeys

In visual studio, I'm using hotkeys they work but if I click off the application they don't work and I need them to

This is my code I'm using

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
     if(e.KeyCode == Keys.B) {
            button1.PerformClick();
     }
}
```

thats all ived tried and i can think of

Comment: so, the hot keys work when you click off your exe and do not work when you have your exe in focus is that correct?

Comment: @CodeWarrior I am reading that the exact opposite way. Focus on App: ok, Focus off Ap : no. Which of course would be expected behavior.

Comment: @Fildor, yes, dyslexia has the better of me there... ive re-read it again and yes... you're right

Comment: Global hot keys are a bad idea: are you going to prevent the user using the B key?

Comment: no im not going to prevent them @Richard

Comment: how do you do global hotkey

Comment: This code does not have any issue, but this will work only if you have focus to Form, if yu have focus to any other element in form, this will not work.....

Comment: What in my head is keylogger... You can search in google with "keylogger vb.net", some have source code with sample for your reference, but I doubt that is a good idea

Comment: @Scorp If you are looking for OS-Level HotKeys (global), check out this article: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/573/how-to-register-a-single-or-multiple-global-hotkeys-for-a-single-key-in-winforms

Answer (score 0):

you have two options in this case:

1. you can register a hotkey in the registry of windows itself.
2. you can use the native winapi keyhook, but in that case the antivirus might work against you